# Can I call a method from a watch and mounted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a functionality (`getAllData` which does an external data query) which I need to call at two occasions: when the component is mounted and when a `prop` changes.

I am however getting a `TypeError: this.getAllData is not a function` when using it in a `watch` and in `mounted`.

Since [methods can be called from methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707738/vuejs-accessing-a-method-from-another-method), I am wondering whether this is true for methods being called from components such as `watch` or `mounted`.

My (simplified) instance is below:

```
export default {
    props: ['triggerReload'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            // some variables
        }
    },
    watch: {
        triggerReload: this.getAllData()
    },
    methods: {
        getAllData: function () {
            // this function correctly fetches external data
        }
    },
    mounted: this.getAllData()
}
```

My workaround will be to either duplicate the code of the function (which is not DRY) <del>or to call an external function (defined outside the Vue instance - which is probably also an anti-pattern)</del> EDIT: this is a component so I do not know how to call an external function and reference the instance (it is not instantiated by `var vm = new Vue(...)`)

Comment: Have you checked what `this` is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can, you just have the wrong syntax, you need (note the extra parenthesis):

```
...
mounted () {
    this.getAllData()
}
```

which is just ES6 sugar for

```
mounted: function mounted () {
    this.getAllData()
}
```

In your version you're binding `mounted` to `this.getAllData` when *creating* the object component, so `this` will refer to the current object, which does not have a `getAllData` method. You need to do it in a function instead so Vue can do its magic and bind `this` to the correct Vue component.

Comment: This answer would profit tremendously from an example how to actually do it right.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but is your second example the working one? If so, then the sentence "which is just ES6 sugar for" is extremely misleading; "sugar" suggests that the two are semantically equivalent so, as the first one is wrong, the second one must be as well.

Comment: The two are correct (and are indeed completely equivalent!). The first one is *not* the code from OP, it's the correct version, I'll clarify what was missing (parentesis)

Comment: Aah, that explains it. Thanks a lot for the clarification!