# Accessing a method from another method and passing value in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I [got](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40708474/5040900) this.

Now, I wan't to know if this is possible

```
computed : {
    X: function(a,b){
      return(a*b)
    },
    Y: function(e){
      var c = this.X(3,2)
      return(c)
    }
}
```

I want to be able to send two arguments `(3,2)` into function:X and then have the computed result sent back to Y. So far, this has failed. I've read [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) but it led me nowhere in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use methods rather than computed:

```
methods: {
    X: function(a,b){
      return(a*b)
    },
    Y: function(e){
      var c = this.X(3,2)
      return(c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, there's a `method` too? I kinda need Y for computed. Can I just use X in the methods?