# Vue.js 2.x TypeScript - Calling a method in another method in the same component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

So in the `<script>` part of a vue file I have something like the following:

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    methods: {
        funcA(x) {
            // more code
        },
        funcB(y) {
            funcA(y)
        },
    },
})

export default class SomeClass extends Vue {}
```

With TypeScript, the above code throws an error of

```
Cannot find name 'funcA'.
```

(It works as intended if defined as JavaScript instead.)

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707738/vuejs-accessing-a-method-from-another-method) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393981/accessing-a-method-from-another-method-and-passing-value-in-vue) and tried using `this.funcA(y)` instead in which it throws an different error of

```
Property 'funcA' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
```

I'm wondering what is the proper way to do this with TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `funcA` and `funcB` methods directly on the class as noted in the docs for
[vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component):

> 1. `methods` can be declared directly as class member methods.

Your component can be modified to the following:

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})

export default class SomeClass extends Vue {
  funcA(x) {
    // more code
  }
  funcB(y) {
    this.funcA(y)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I actually added `funcA(x)` as part of `data()` as a workaround (then called `this.$data.funcA(y)` in `funcB(y)`) but this is definitely more elegant than that.