# VueJS How to access Mounted() variables in Methods

Tags: vue.js

I'm new in Vue and would like assistance on how to access and use variables created in `Mounted()` in my methods.

I have this code

Template

```
<select class="controls" @change="getCatval()">
```

Script

```
mounted() {
    var allcards = this.$refs.allcards;
    var mixer = mixitup(allcards);
  },
methods: {
    getCatval() {
      var category = event.target.value;
      // I want to access mixer here;
    }
  }
```

I can't find a solution anywhere besides this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40708474/4897281) where I could call a `method x` from `mounted()` and pass mixer to it then use it inside my `getCatval()`

Is there an easier way to access those variables?

Comment: Use arrow function instead of normal function xxx(args).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will first suggest you to stop using `var`, and use the latest, `let` and `const` to declare variable

You have to first declare a variable in `data()`:

```
data(){
  return {
    allcards: "",
    mixer: ""
  }
}
```

and then in your `mounted()`:

```
mounted() {
  this.allcards = this.$refs.allcards;
  this.mixer = mixitup(this.allcards);
},
methods: {
  getCatval() {
    let category = event.target.value;
    
    this.mixer
  }
}
```

Comment: is there no other way than having them returned from data()

Comment: `this.$refs` is not reactive anyway, so there's no need to cache it into the data store on the mounted lifecycle hook. Just do `this.mixer = mixitup(this.$refs.allcards)` is sufficient.

Comment: This makes the variable reactive, if you dont want the overhead of reactivity, there must be a better way ?

Answer (score 2):

like Ninth Autumn said : object returned by the `data` function and `props` of your components are defined as **attributes** of the component, like your methods defined in the `method` attribute of a component, it's in `this` so you can use it everywhere in your component !

Here an example:

```
  data() {
    return {
      yourVar: 'hello',
    };
  },
  mounted() { this.sayHello(); },
  method: {
    sayHello() { console.log(this.yourVar); },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

you cannot pass any value outside if it's in block scope - Either you need to get it from a common place or set any common value

---

As I can see,  `var mixer = mixitup(allcards);` is in the end acting as a `function` which does some operation with `allcards` passed to it and then returns a value.

1 - **Place it to different `helper` file if `mixitup` is totally independent and not using any `vue` props used by your component**

In your `helper.js`

```
const mixitup = cards => {
  // Do some operation with cards
  let modifiedCards = 'Hey I get returned by your function'
  return modifiedCards
}

export default {
    mixitup
}
```

And then in your `vue` file just `import` it and use it is as a `method`.

In `yourVue.vue`

```
import Helpers from '...path../helpers'

 const mixitup = Helpers.mixitup

 export default {
    name: 'YourVue',
    data: ...,
    computed: ...,
    mounted() {
      const mixer = mixitup(allcards)
    },
    methods: {
       mixitup, // this will make it as `vue` method and accessible through 
         this
       getCatval() {
          var category = event.target.value;
          this.mixitup(allcards)
        }
    }
  }
```

2- **Use it as `mixins` if your `mixitup` dependent to your `vue` and have access to `vue` properties**

In your `yourVueMixins.js`:

```
export default {
    methods: {
         mixitup(cards) {
          // Do some operation with cards
          let modifiedCards = 'Hey I get returned by your function'
          return modifiedCards
        }
    }
}
```

And `import` it in your `vue` file:

```
 import YourVueMixins from '...mixins../YourVueMixins'

 const mixitup = Helpers.mixitup

 export default {
    name: 'YourVue',
    mixins: [YourVueMixins] // this will have that function as vue property
    data: ...,
    computed: ...,
    mounted() {
      const mixer = this.mixitup(allcards)
    },
    methods: {
       getCatval() {
          var category = event.target.value;
          this.mixitup(allcards)
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how do I access mixer in getCatVal()

Comment: I can try to help you more if you could explain what will be the `mixer` - if its having value returned by `fn` then I have give you example above. In short you cannot `pass` any value outside if it's in `block` scope - Either you need to get it from a common place or set any common value

Comment: mixer initialize the mixitup plugin and can then be used to filter cards

Comment: Have you tried the second way I have explained in my example or the first one? - Initialize your mixitup plugin in different file and import it as mixin - now when component get mounted just execute the method and do your next job